# Windows kernel use \Device\HarddiskVolume5 or some other number disk as the RootDirectory for OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES

Tags: windows, winapi, wdk, windows-kernel, minifilter

I need to call ZwCreateFile with a relative path, with the path being relative to the root of a \Device\HarddiskVolumeSomeNumber using InitializeObjectAttributes.

For example, I would like to use the string "path.txt" as ObjectName and a handle to "\Device\HarddiskVolume5" as RootDirectory.

My problem is obtaining a HANDLE object for the device directory.  It seems ZwOpenFile and ZwOpenDirectory are not able to open these paths, even though I am able to open a file such as \Device\HarddiskVolume5\hello.txt

How must I obtain a HANDLE object for use as RootDirectory in OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES?

Edit: Changed title to say 5 instead of 1.  I am aware that some numbered Harddisks such as 1 are not normal filesystems, such as partition data.

Comment: `ZwOpenDirectory` not exist such api. `ZwOpenDirectoryObject` exist. and possible with it open *\Device\Harddisk%u* . not exist any problems here. and you can not open *\Device\Harddisk5\hello.txt* - because no such object exist.

Comment: @RbMm I'm using ZwOpenDirectoryObject and I'm getting STATUS_OBJECT_TYPE_MISMATCH

Comment: I'm pretty sure you want to open the root directory of the filesystem that's mounted on the disk volume device `"\\Device\\HarddiskVolume<N>\\"` via `ZwOpenFile`. Note the required trailing backslash. Without the trailing backslash, it's a path for the volume device itself.

Comment: @RbMm https://pastebin.com/vk0tbBkg

Comment: @ErykSun I've tried trailing slash too, doesn't seem to change my results.

Comment: you are not understand different between nt directory object and file systems files. `&name_info->Volume`  - absolute sure that here not *Device\Harddisk<N>*

Comment: @RbMm the string contents of `&name_info->Volume` are `\Device\HarddiskVolume3` in that example.  Can I use ZwOpenDirectoryObject to open the directory just the Harddisk?

Comment: Check the name I gave you. The name you're using is not a device name. It's an object directory that contains the physical disk device, `"DR<N>"`, as well as symlinks to the volume devices partitioned on it (e.g. something like `"\\Device\\Harddisk5\\Partition1"` -> `"\\Device\\HarddiskVolume10"`). Even with the correct path in `"\\Device"`, this is stil out of the norm. Usually one would use the persistent name in the device alias directory `"\\??"`, such as `"\\??\\C:\\"` or `"\\??\\Volume{GUID}\\"`.

Comment: @ErykSun sorry, mistyped.  My string contents are something like `\Device\HarddiskVolume3`.  I also tried with a trailing \.  I do not have the option to use a path such as \\??\\C:\\.

Comment: i very strong doubt that you use exactly *\Device\Harddisk3* and got error `STATUS_OBJECT_TYPE_MISMATCH`. also `DIRECTORY_ALL_ACCESS` - for what ? you not open it from user mode with such access

Comment: @NoahGreenberg - again `\Device\HarddiskVolume3` and `\Device\Harddisk3` is absolute different things ( device object and directory object (but not fs directory !)) the `ZwOpenDirectoryObject` and `ZwOpenFile` absolute different api, etc.

Comment: Why can't you use `"\\??\\"` or `"\\??\\Global"`? That's a valid NT path. Also, note that I said to use `ZwOpenFile`. You're mentioning `ZwOpenDirectoryObject` makes no sense. It is not a directory object. It's a filesystem directory that needs to be opened with `ZwOpenFile` or `ZwCreateFile`.

Comment: @NoahGreenberg, okay, that's fine then.

Comment: @RbMm, I meant `"\\??\\Global"`. Device alias directories are set per logon session as `"\\Sessions\\0\\DosDevices\\<logon ID>"`. Each one contains a symlink to the corresponding global device directory, which happens to be `"\\GLOBAL??"` in all normal cases. (The object manager has direct references to the two object directories via the logon-session record, but just for efficiency.) Note that the SYSTEM logon uses `"\\GLOBAL??"` for its `"\\??\\"` device-alias directory, but it's okay because even in `"\\GLOBAL??"` you'll find a `"Global"` link that points back to `"\\GLOBAL??"`.